# Counting Syllables in an Array

Tags: c

I am trying to count all syllables in each word of a string that I passed into an array.

A syllable counts as two vowels adjacent to each other (a, e, i , o ,u, y). For example, the "ee" in "peel" counts as 1 syllable. But, the "u" and "e" in "juked" count as 2 syllables. The "e" at the end of a word does not count as a syllable. Also, each word has at least 1 syllable even if the previous rules don't apply.

I have a file that contained a large string (words, spaces, and newlines) that I passed into an array.
I have code that counts each word by counting the whitespace between them and newlines. See below:

```
for (i = 0; i < lengthOfFile; i++)
{
    if (charArray[i] == ' ' || charArray[i] == '\n')
    {
      wordCount++;
    }
  }
```

Where `charArray` is the file that is passed into an array `(freads)` and `lengthOfFile` is the total bytes in the file counted by `(fseek)` and `wordCount` is total words counted.

From here, I need to somehow count the syllables in each word in the array but don't know where to start.

Comment: A minimal example would start with a preconstructed list of words. How you read and parse the list is irrelevant to the question you claim to be asking. It seems to be fluff to distract from the fact that the is no attempt to solve the actual problem being shown.

Comment: if you are using c or c++ then traverse the words and check condition on each word you find.

Comment: The approach is simple. After identifying a 'word', loop over the characters in word identifying each group of vowels that ends with a non-vowel character. From your description, that will provide your syllable count.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin once i identify a word, do i have to store it separately in an array of strings to be able to loop over it?

Comment: No, you don't really need to store anything. (unless you want to), just reset your syllable count to zero each time a space is encountered, then start your syllable count as you output each character, when the next space (or EOF) is found, output the count and a newline, repeat.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I apologize for all the questions, I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this. If I were to do what you said, would i have to set up if statements that check to see if the array has 'aa' || 'ae' || 'ai' etc (and every other combination of vowels) found inside it? (Also, I need a TOTAL syllable count for the entire array. Not just for each word).

Comment: For a total, just add word `syllcnt` to a `totalcnt` before you reset when a space is found.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having trouble, it's only because you are overthinking the problem. Whenever you are counting, determining frequency, etc.., you can normally simplify things by using a "State-Loop". A state-loop is nothing more than a loop where you loop over each character (or whatever) and handle whatever state you find yourself in, like:

- have I read any characters? (if not, handle that state);
- is the current character a space? (if so, assuming no multiple-spaces for simplicity, you have reached the end of a word, handle that state);
- is the current character a non-space and non-vowel? (if so, if my last character was a vowel, increment my syllable count); and
- what do I need to do regardless of the classification of the current char? (output it, set last = current, etc..)

That's basically it and can be translated into a single loop with a number of tests to handle each state. You can also add a check to insure that words like `"my"` and `"he"` are counted as a single syllable by checking if your syllable count is zero when you reach the end of the word.

Putting it altogether, you could write a basic implementation like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void) {

    char c, last = 0;                       /* current & last char */
    const char *vowels = "AEIOUYaeiouy";    /* vowels (plus Yy) */
    size_t syllcnt = 0, totalcnt = 0;       /* word syllable cnt & total */

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {        /* read each character */
        if (!last) {                        /* if 1st char (no last) */
            putchar (c);                    /* just output it */
            last = c;                       /* set last */
            continue;                       /* go get next */
        }

        if (isspace (c)) {                  /* if space, end of word */
            if (!syllcnt)                   /* if no syll, it's 1 (he, my) */
                syllcnt = 1;
            printf (" - %zu\n", syllcnt);   /* output syll cnt and '\n' */
            totalcnt += syllcnt;            /* add to total */
            syllcnt = 0;                    /* reset syllcnt to zero */
        }   /* otherwise */
        else if (!strchr (vowels, c))       /* if not vowel */
            if (strchr (vowels, last))      /* and last was vowel */
                syllcnt++;                  /* increment syllcnt */

        if (!isspace (c))                   /* if not space */
            putchar (c);                    /* output it */
        last = c;                           /* set last = c */
    }
    printf ("\n  total syllables: %zu\n", totalcnt);
}
```

(**note:** as mentioned above, this simple example implementation does not consider multiple spaces between words -- which you can simply add as another needed condition by checking whether `!isspace (last)`. Can you figure out where that check should be added, hint: it's added to an existing check with `&&` -- fine tuning is left to you)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "my dog eats banannas he peels while getting juked" | ./syllablecnt
my - 1
dog - 1
eats - 1
banannas - 3
he - 1
peels - 1
while - 1
getting - 2
juked - 2

  total syllables: 13
```

If you need to read words from a file, simply redirect the file as input to the program on `stdin`, e.g.

```
./syllablecnt < inputfile
```

**Edit - Reading from File into Dynamically Allocated Buffer**

Following on from the comments about wanting to read from a file (or `stdin`) into a dynamically sized buffer and then traversing the buffer to output the syllables per-word and total syllables, you could do something like the following that simply reads all characters from a file into a buffer initially allocated holding 8-characters and is reallocated as needed (doubling the allocation size each time a `realloc` is needed). That is a fairly standard and reasonably efficient buffer growth strategy. You are free to grow it by any size you like, but avoid many small rabbit-pellet reallocations as memory allocation is relatively expensive from a computing standpoint.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define NCHAR 8     /* initial characters to allocate */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char c, last = 0, *buffer;              /* current, last & pointer */
    const char *vowels = "AEIOUYaeiouy";    /* vowels */
    size_t syllcnt = 0, totalcnt = 0,       /* word syllable cnt & total */
            n = 0, size = NCHAR;
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("fopen-file");
        return 1;
    }

    /* allocate/validate initial NCHAR buffer size */
    if (!(buffer = malloc (size))) {
        perror ("malloc-buffer");
        return 1;
    }

    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {        /* read each character */
        buffer[n++] = c;                    /* store, increment count */
        if (n == size) {                    /* reallocate as required */
            void *tmp = realloc (buffer, 2 * size);
            if (!tmp) {                     /* validate realloc */
                perror ("realloc-tmp");
                break;      /* still n good chars in buffer */
            }
            buffer = tmp;   /* assign reallocated block to buffer */
            size *= 2;      /* update allocated size */
        }
    }
    if (fp != stdin)        /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {        /* loop over all characters */
        c = buffer[i];                      /* set to c to reuse code */
        if (!last) {                        /* if 1st char (no last) */
            putchar (c);                    /* just output it */
            last = c;                       /* set last */
            continue;                       /* go get next */
        }

        if (isspace(c) && !isspace(last)) { /* if space, end of word */
            if (!syllcnt)                   /* if no syll, it's 1 (he, my) */
                syllcnt = 1;
            printf (" - %zu\n", syllcnt);   /* output syll cnt and '\n' */
            totalcnt += syllcnt;            /* add to total */
            syllcnt = 0;                    /* reset syllcnt to zero */
        }   /* otherwise */
        else if (!strchr (vowels, c))       /* if not vowel */
            if (strchr (vowels, last))      /* and last was vowel */
                syllcnt++;                  /* increment syllcnt */

        if (!isspace (c))                   /* if not space */
            putchar (c);                    /* output it */
        last = c;                           /* set last = c */
    }
    free (buffer);      /* don't forget to free what you allocate */

    printf ("\n  total syllables: %zu\n", totalcnt);
}
```

(you can do the same using `fgets` or using POSIX `getline`, or allocate all at once with your `fseek/ftell` or `stat` and then `fread` the entire file into a buffer in a single call -- up to you)

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/syllablecnt_array dat/syllables.txt
==19517== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==19517== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==19517== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==19517== Command: ./bin/syllablecnt_array dat/syllables.txt
==19517==
my - 1
dog - 1
eats - 1
banannas - 3
he - 1
peels - 1
while - 1
getting - 2
juked - 2

  total syllables: 13
==19517==
==19517== HEAP SUMMARY:
==19517==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19517==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 672 bytes allocated
==19517==
==19517== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==19517==
==19517== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==19517== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance David. I understand your code and how it works. I was wondering if it's possible to read the characters out of an array. Would it be possible to get rid of the while loop and replace it with a for loop that traverses the entire array? What would have to be changed in the other code for this to work?

Comment: Sure, no problems. It doesn't matter where you are traversing the characters, it would be exactly the same for all practical purposes. I just skipped the step of reading into an array and just traversed the characters in the read buffer. Why it won't be any faster/slower is C provides an IO buffer (of 8192 bytes on Linux), so you are reading from memory and not doing individual reads from the file for each char. The only trick here will be allocating to handle any size input. Use POSIX `getline` if you have it, otherwise `malloc` and `fgets` or a fixed array large enough.

Comment: Do you need help with an example allocating/reading the input into an array? If so I can drop an edit and add that part. Not knowing if you have `getline`, I would just allocate an initial buffer size of say 1024-bytes and then use `fgets` (or even `fgetc`) to loop keeping track of the number characters read, and if I reach the current allocation limit, just `realloc` the array and keep going. If you know you will not have more than say 1024 chars of input, just declare `char buffer[1024];` and don' t read more than that. If so, let me know if you have `getline` (makes it easy)

Comment: Wow, thank you again for the tips! Earlier on in my code, I have used `fseek` and `ftell` to figure out the size of the file being read. I then used `malloc` to allocate enough memory for the specific file being read. The file is then passed into that array which allows me to do what I wish with it (count syllables!). I have messed around with the code you provided and ended up being able to get it to work with the array! Thank you again for your help.

Comment: You can do it that way, or just use `stat` and a stat-buffer (e.g. `sbuf`) and the file size is in `sbuf.st_size`. Why I generally use `malloc/realloc` or `getline` is it provides the flexibility to read from `stdin` or a file. No one approach is better than the other, just fit your situation. Reading from an array, just replace the `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)` with either a `for` loop indexing the characters, or just declare a pointer to your buffer and use a `while (*p)` loop. Either way, if you just declare `char c = buffer[i]`, at the beginning, you can re-use the same code.

Comment: Added a dynamic allocation example for you.

Comment: I appreciate the update but unfortunately I am not that proficient with C to understand that code yet. I do have another question, how would I get the program to not count double spaces as syllables?

Comment: `if (isspace(c) && !isspace(last))` is the answer to the original question I posed to you in my original answer.